# Books for multivariable Calculus.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have several books for advanced calculus, but in each of the book there is little portion of two variable calculus. I like to study mutlivariable calculus, specially derivative as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$  to $\mathbb{R}^{m}.$ Please suggest me best books in which i can clear my concept about derivative as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$  to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* has a comprehensive chapter on multivariable differentiation and applications. He spends a couple pages giving the necessary linear algebra prerequisites and two pages setting the scene for thinking of derivatives as linear transformations. The exercises in chapter 9 are fairly computational in comparison to other chapter exercises, most likely to help build intuition.